# How to prevent vscode show snippets on strings

Tags: string, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets

When I'm typing a **string** in **VSCode**, especially **paths**, sometimes I want to use the autocomplete function, so I can see the available files and folders while I type, but instead VSCode shows me all of these **snippets**.

[image: Observed autocomplete function behavior]

There's an option to put snippets at the end of the predictions, but I don't want that behavior always, just when I'm typing a path.  Is there a way to do so? Thanks in advance